# In what class do you learn how to solve integral equations?

Tags: integral-equations

I was interested in knowing in what class does one learn Fredholm theory (integral equations). Any textbook recommendations for learning how to solve integral equations?

Comment: Integration is a fundamental concept of **calculus**.

Comment: I understand integration is a concept in calculus. I should have been more specific with this question. I apologize. I meant concepts such as Fredholm theory.

Comment: Well, then your first question becomes a very broad and probably unanswerable one (country, university and study dependent) but the book reference part is a good question, although already asked.